# ICS: external microsd storage card: can i use it with camera and not encrypt?

Tags: security, external-sd

So, I just bought a microSD card for my Ice Cream Sandwich phone. I put it in, it's recognized. But it appears I must encrypt it before I can use it for the camera's storage, otherwise if it is not encrypted, it is read-only.

Is there no other way?

I see, with it encrypted, I must create a PIN or password to access the phone. Previously, I just used a pattern, but now it seems I cannot do just the pattern.

I don't care if it is encrypted, but I want my pattern back. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a random idea -- if you go to Settings / Security / Device Administrators, are any programs listed?  If so, perhaps they're the ones that are demanding that you encrypt your SD card.

Comment: That is odd. What device is this?

Comment: Interesting.. more details are required to answer.

Comment: @offby1: only Lookout Antivirus is listed there, which I've had since I had the phone, so I doubt it is the cause.

Comment: @AlEverett an HTC Droid Incredible 4G LTE

Comment: I'm also on ICS 4.0.4. What I've noticed so far: If I go to Settings>Security>Screen Lock, I have the following greyed out: "None" "Face Unlock", "Pattern". Only options available in black are: "PIN" and "Password". I set a PIN. Underneath each of those greyed out, it says "Disabled by administrator, encryption policy, or credential storage." Under Settings>Storage > Storage Card, I have "Storage Card encryption" checked, because it said my card would be read-only if I did not encrypt it. I tested in read-only, unencrypted mode, and in the camera options, it wouldnt let me to write to the card

Comment: And for testing purposes, I'm going to be reluctant to unencrypt and reencrypt, because it has to wipe the data to do so, and as I learned the hard way, it wipes the data both in this new external SD card and that fake, virtual, internal "SD Card" partition, both at once. (So if you are some future reader, reading this, before you encrypt: backup your pictures, music, videos! Or you'll lose 'em. Fortunately I had instant upload from Google+ turned on, but Google+ shrinks them down to slightly less than original quality, sadly.)

Comment: Just a wild guess: Do you have some Exchange account configured? Your security settings (only PIN and Password available) make me think so. In that case, it might be a policy that came along with it...

Comment: No, not using Exchange. I discovered this though: when I unencrypted the SD card, leaving the camera set to store on SD card, it does, though if I go to that menu, it still warns me it "cannot", even though it does. I'm afraid to select "Phone Storage" instead of "Storage Card" in the camera now, afraid it won't go back to "Storage Card" (SD Card) without my going through the rigmarole again (of encrypting the SD Card again, losing all of my data on both it and the phone's internal, virtual "SD Card", reinstalling all apps on the SD Card and restoring photos, then unencrypting).